# See full content of Stash in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way in SourceTree to see the whole content of a stash?

I have stashed quite a bunch of changes that are not yet ready to be committed on the `Develop` branch in order to checkout the `Master` branch for a hotfix. Now I realize that one change in the stash would be good to include in the hotfix since I will anyway have to make a new deployment. But since the stash is largish, I cannot see the particular change I want when I select the stash in SourceTree. For me, SourceTree shows only a part of the stash as some kind of summary...

I know that I can get around this in several different ways, but if there is an option somewhere that I don't know of which would make SourceTree show the full contents of the stash, I'd be very pleased if someone could tell me where to find it.

The repository is a `GIT` repository if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Can be fixed (in latest version?) by increasing the `Max File Count` and `Max Diff Line Count` in the `Tools > Options > Diff`:

[image]

Comment: For anyone wondering, the upper limit for these values is `2147483647` (the Java Integer upper limit). It seems SourceTree needs be restarted for the changes to take effect. Also, in my case, I found the stash diff was still limiting to 100 lines in SourceTree 3.0.15.

Comment: The 100 line limit for new files in a stash is still unfixed in Sourcetree 3.3.9. Also see https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/View-whole-stash-in-SourceTree/qaq-p/166728

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I don't see the "Max File Count" field on SourceTree 4.0.1 (234) on macOS.

One ugly trick to see the whole stash is:

1. Copy your project folder and open the folder with SourceTree.
2. Discard all active changes.
3. Apply your stash.
4. Copy or check any code you might need.

Answer (score 0):

One day I had saved 74,000+ changes into stash and later was not able to observe them in SourceTree even though I set Max file count to 2147483647 as @huysentruitw suggests.

What helped is to load folder into MS Visual Studio 2022 go to Git / Commit or Stash... and here after some time all my changes were shown.

Answer (score -3):

This question have been asked here [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725729/git-see-whats-in-a-stash-without-applying-stash) than [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git).

```
git stash show -p stash@{0}
```

is the command you are looking for.

Or if you want to add a small script you can do these following steps:

```
git config --edit --global
```

under the [alias] section write:

```
whatsInStash = "!f() { git stash show -p stash@{$1}; }; f"
```

And to call it:

```
git whatsInStash 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in my case the question is primarily about `SourceTree`. I like using a GUI instead of fiddling with the command line, so I'd really like it if I could get the `SourceTree` GUI to show the whole content of the stash... It might not be possible, but for now I'm going to hold off on accepting the answer...

Comment: In my case I wanted to output the whole stash to a file so I could then copy and paste lines various lines from *new* files in the stash. Just adding `> stash.txt` wasn't quite enough as the output had `+` symbols next to each line. Found a way around this by using the following command: `git stash show -p stash@{0} --color-words --color=never > stash.txt`.