# git stash show -p returns fatal error

Tags: git

When I run `git stash list`, I get the following:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on mybranch: 123456f Generic comment here.
stash@{1}: WIP on mybranch: 234567g Generic comment here.
...
stash@{n}: WIP on mybranch: 345678h Generic comment here.
```

This is expected behavior.  What mystifies me is `git show`'s behavior.

When I run `git stash show -p stash@{1}` in my repo, I get the following error:

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@{1}': unknown revision or path not in working tree.`

How can this be?  I'm running `git stash show -p stash@{1}` in a git repo.

Comment: That does seem impossible. It means `git rev-parse` is failing to translate `stash@{1}` into a Git object ID, and yet `git stash list` simply shows all the reflog entries for the `stash` ref, so if it shows `stash@{1}` then `stash@{1}` is a valid name for an object ID. (The "on the right branch" part is irrelevant: stashes are on *no* branch.)

Comment: What Git version shows this error and with what Git version was the repository created (cloned)?

Comment: `git version 1.8.0` for both showing the error and the repo it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell was eating up my own curly braces.

`git stash show -p stash@'{1'}` works.

Ironically, it was the least upvoted answer @ [Is it possible to preview stash contents in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git) that answered my question.

Just weird because the error reported the command with curly braces.  You'd expect it to report it without them.

Comment: In fact, my shell does that as well, but the error message *does* show it without the curly braces: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@2': ...` It seems impossible. What OS are you on (and why is your Git so old? :-) these may have the same answer...)