# execute perl script as passed argument

Tags: windows, perl, command-line

Im trying to execute a perl script as a passed argument from the command line. I compiled a c file and named it "Test", so trying to pass an argument I try this

```
>Test perl -e "print qq{A\n}x500"
```

which I want to mean, run Test file and pass 500 A's, but it seems to not be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it should work? It runs `Test` and passes 3 arguments to it - `perl`, `-e`, `"print qq{A\n}\x500"`. In bash it would be:

```
Test `perl -a "print qq{A\n}x500"`
```

For windows, there is no simple way to get a programs output as a variable or pass it to another command directly.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows), it describes how set a commands output to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a pipe, you were latterly  passing `perl -e "print qq{A\n}x500"` to `Test`.

Example of using a pipe :

```
perl -e "print qq{A\n}x500" | Test
```