# Batch File: FOR /F doesn't work if path has spaces

Tags: batch-file

This is the problem I'm having:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM If this batch file is run in the same directory as "command.exe" then the
REM following line will work.
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (`command.exe "C:\File Being Passed as a Parameter.txt"`) DO ECHO %%A

REM The following line does not work no matter where this batch file is run.
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (`"C:\Folder With Spaces\command.exe" "C:\File Being Passed as a Parameter.txt"`) DO ECHO %%A
```

I would like to store this batch file wherever I want and not be forced to store it in the same folder as command.exe. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `CALL` before the program name:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (`CALL "C:\Folder With Spaces\command.exe" "C:\File Being Passed as a Parameter.txt"`) DO ECHO %%A
```

Comment: Why to use `call` with an EXE?

Comment: @jeb: In this particular case, to work around the problem in question.

Comment: You are right, I tested it and it seems that only the way with a `call` works

Answer (score 13):

The `call` trick of [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m) is clever and works fine, but I tried to understand the problem here.

This problem is caused by the `cmd.exe`, as you can read at `cmd /help`

> ....
>   the first and the last quote will be removed, when there are
>   not exactly two quotes in the line.
>   ...

So there is also another solution with simply adding two extra quotes

```
FOR /F "usebackq=" %%A IN (`""C:\Folder Space\myCmd.exe" "Param space""`) DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

Comment: That is exactly right! Just adding some examples here. This works: `FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN (\`cmd.exe /C "findstr.exe" /?\`) DO @ECHO %A` (quotes only around *one* argument). This works too: `FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN (\`"cmd.exe" /C findstr.exe /?\`) DO @ECHO %A` (quotes *only* around the command). This does *not* work until another pair of double quotes is added like you've suggested: `FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN (\`"cmd.exe" /C "findstr.exe" /?\`) DO @ECHO %a`.

Comment: USEBACKQ is not needed, and better to use `'^""c:\folder space\myCmd.exe" "param with ^poison char"^"'` so that poison characters are still quoted properly.

Comment: So it seems like it would always be safe to use surrounding quotes as a best practice. This also keep you from having to escape the pipe as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Careful:**

**Using 'call' (as shown by Andriy M) seems the safest option.**

I found a case where adding leading and trailing double quotes (as suggested as a possible solution by jeb) has a problem.

**Problem:**

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('""C:\path with spaces\hello.bat" "filename with an & ampersand.jpg""') do ( echo output=%%i )`

cmd.exe's output: `& was unexpected at this time.`

**Solution:**

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('call "C:\path with spaces\hello.bat" "filename with an & ampersand.jpg"') do ( echo output=%%i )`

Comment: That's right, other characters like () can lead to problems as well. This can easily happen with paths like `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`.