# Batch file - Deleting files with a name matching this regex OR that regex but NOT that one

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, dos

I try to write a Windows batch file to delete all files in a directory matching ((`regex1` *or* `regex2`) *and not* `regex3`).

I'm able to delete files matching a regular expression using something like:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
    'dir /a-d /b *.* ^| findstr /r /c:"^test[0-9]*.jar$"'
) do del "%%a"
```

But I have no idea how I can say :

1. this regex *or* this one.
2. but *not* this one

~~~

**UPDATE**

A better example of what I'm trying to do :

The `.bat` file would be automatically ran at the end of the extraction of a [7-zip's SFX](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm) (self-extracting) executable. This executable will update some versioned jars inside a folder structure.

Let's say the executable will extract a `test-1.0.2.jar` file inside a `lib` folder. If this exact file (same version) already exists, then it is overwritten, this already works well since it is managed by the SFX executable itself. But if there already are other versions of the same file in the `lib` folder, I want the .bat file to delete them! For example :

- `test-1.0.1.jar`
- `test-1.0.3.jar`
- `test-1.0.jar`
- `test-1.jar`
- `test.jar`

...would have to be deleted.

But those must *not* be deleted :

- `test-1.0.2.jar` (the new file itself)
- `test-test2-1.0.0.jar` (not a version of the same file)

I'm currently not able to express that using only *one* regex in the .bat , because `findstr`'s regex capabilities are pretty limited. But if I was able to say :

Anything that is :

- `^test.jar$`
  or
- `^test-[0-9]+.jar$`
  or
- `^test-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.jar$`
  or
- `^test-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.jar$`

... must be deleted **except** :

- `test-1.0.2.jar`

Then it would work.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please provide specific data to test? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @stribizhev I updated my question to give a better example of what I need to achieve. And, no, except for the `for do` code I already posted, I didn't find anything else helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the most recent version, then I should think you would want to preserve test-1.0.3.jar, not test-1.0.2.jar. But I'll assume you know what you are doing.

This is easily solved using my [JREN.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

JREN.BAT is really is intended to rename files (or folders) via regex replacement. But there is a /LIST option that simply lists the result, without actually renaming anything. The /RFM option specifies a regex file mask to determine which files are to be included. The /FX option is used to specify an exclusion list.

from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('jren "^" "" /list /fx "test-1.1.2.jar" /rfm "^test(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$"') do del "%F"
```

Or from within a batch script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'jren "^" "" /list /fx "test-1.1.2.jar" /rfm "^test(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$"'
) do del "%%F"
```

***Update in response to comment***

To delete files from `"%dp0lib"` (see OP's comment), you could use (note that `%dp0` already ends with `\`):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'jren "^" "" /list /fx "test-1.1.2.jar" /rfm "^test(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$" /p "%~dp0lib"'
) do del "%~dp0lib\%%F"
```

or

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0lib"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'jren "^" "" /list /fx "test-1.1.2.jar" /rfm "^test(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$"'
) do del "%%F"
popd
```

**Final update to support spaces in path when PATH does not point to jren**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '^""%~dp0jren.bat" "^" "" /list /fx "test-1.1.2.jar" /rfm "^test(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$" /p "%~dp0lib"^"'
) do del "%~dp0lib\%%F"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! Also : yes I may want to delete a newer version of the files since the executable may be used to rollback to a previous version if a problem is found in the latest version.

Comment: There is a missing "%" for the last "%%F" in your batch script example. Other than that it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: One last question if you don't mind : if I want to specify the directory where `jren ` will search in (the "RootPath"), I use `/P some_dir` right? But what if this directory contains spaces? My rootpath is currently `%~dp0\lib`, but if the `.bat` file itself is in a directory with spaces, it doesn't work! Any idea? I don't find a way to properly escape everything! In fact, I want to prefix all paths with `%~dp0`! For example : `%~dp0jren`. But using double-quotes doesn't seem t work...

Comment: From my current tests, only the `pushd/popd` trick seems to work and I'm not sure why. But thanks a bunch... Stackoverflow is great because people like you!

Comment: Just for the records : again, the `pushd/popd` trick works well. The reason why the other solution doesn't work for me, is when I try to prepend `jren` with `%~dp0` : `%~dp0jren`. *That* doesn't work when there are spaces in the path. I tried wrapping it with double-quotes and/or with ticks, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: @electrotype - Ahhh - I see the problem. I'm assuming you have JREN.BAT somewhere within your PATH, so you can simply run it using JREN, regardless what your current directory is. If PATH does not point to JREN.BAT, then yes, you need to specify the path. In order to include spaces, you must surround the path with quotes. If you use quotes, then you must include the .BAT extension. `"%~dp0lib\jren.bat"`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. In a `test.bat` file, next to `jren.bat` : `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('"%~dp0jren.bat" "^" "" /list /rfm "^test$"') do echo %%F`. This still gives an error when those two files are in a path with spaces.

Comment: @electrotype - Oooh, I forgot about this comlication: [Batch File: FOR /F doesn't work if path has spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6474738/1012053). I've provided one last update to solve that problem.