# for /f "usebackq" with spaces

Tags: for-loop

I am trying to put the a .jar file path into a var... but It's killing me!
I have problems with spaces.... I tried all combinations possible with `'´" and no lucky...

Can't pass "%programfiles(x86)%\java" as parameter to "where" command :(

Obviously I'm not putting well the special characters, but not discover how to do it!

Also checked all options in:
[Batch File: FOR /F doesn't work if path has spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474738/batch-file-for-f-doesnt-work-if-path-has-spaces)

```
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (''where /r '%programfiles(x86)%\java file.jar'') do set "jarpath=%%f"

for /f "usebackq" %%f in ("where /r `%programfiles(x86)%\java`" file.jar) do set "jarpath=%%f"

for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`where /r` "%programfiles(x86)%\java" file.jar) do set "jarpath=%%f"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  if you need...

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`where /r "%programfiles(x86)%\java" file.jar`) do set jarfile=%%f
```