# Batch FOR loop running an application with spaces in the pathname and the path is not static

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, path, escaping, return-value

**To begin**, this isn't a duplicate of all the questions about path names with spaces (when running `dir` commands in a `for` loop) or any other similar questions because of one important fact: my path is NOT static and is instead made into a variable and passed into the loop that way. None of their previous questions solved my issue, I've been trying for awhile now. I also need to use a `FOR` loop, I can't put this command outside of a `FOR` loop. The reason is because the application I am running has output that I need to check in batch without external files (work requirements). The workflow is like this:

1. Batch does stuff
2. Batch runs a C# script and waits using a `FOR` loop
3. C# script does stuff
4. C# script returns with output that batch can read (it prints to console)
5. Batch `FOR` loop that calls the C# script finishes, reads the output
6. batch reports state of C# script based on what it found.

**The problem** is when using the escape characters inside the `FOR` `IN` clause.
To run an external application where the path has spaces, usually it goes like this:

```
"<path with spaces>"<application name> <other arguments>
```

In my code I'm doing this (names kept secret because it's for work):

```
"C:\my new folder"MyScript.exe | FIND "the output"
```

Which works well and good even when the path is a variable like this:

```
"%thePath%"MyScript.exe | FIND "the output"
```

The problem is that when I try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('"%thePath%"MyScript.exe ^| FIND "the output"') DO (REM put code here)
```

It NEVER actually runs the command. Instead I get the error: `'C:\my' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
Which clearly means that the path is being split by spaces and interpreted as the command. 
**So I tried:**

1. adding double quotes to the `FOR`, didn't work. Just returned a syntax error.
2. adding double quotes to the variable when it is `SET`, a syntax error.
3. taking away the quotes, it split the path.
4. putting the whole command in one string and then running `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('TheWholeCommandAsAString')`. it split the path.
5. Tried step four with all the various quotation combinations. it split the path.
6. I've tried a trick  I heard about from a forum, putting `"delims="` in the `FOR` loop. it split the path.
7. I've tried all the permuatations of having `tokens=* delims=` and `usebackq` in my `FOR` loop while also doing the above tests, none of the permutations worked they all split the path.

Clearly, something about the path being in a variable inside a `FOR` loop is the issue here because when the variable expands, no matter what quotation I put around the path, the `FOR` loop thinks it is multiple commands and uses the first one.

**My question** is: what syntax do I need to use for this very specific case. I need the path in the `FOR` loop, I need the path to be dynamic, I can't use the start command, I can't use text file output, these are all work requirements and no I definitely cannot negotiate any of them. I'm in no position to do so. I just need:

```
"%thePath%"MyScript.exe | FIND "the output"
```

Ran as the whole command in a `FOR` loop where I think it should be:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('"%thePath%"MyScript.exe ^| FIND "the output"') DO (REM put code here)
```

but clearly it isn't so what IS the correct way to do this? Anything that allows me to capture the output of MyScript.exe (given the requirements) is fine. I can't use start because that would give me the output of the start command (AKA nothing).

Comment: In my world, when a path has spaces I include the entire file path in quotes.  Not just the path or just the file name. `"c:\some path\some folder\my program.exe"`

Comment: Put a `CALL` in front `... ('CALL "%thePath%"MyScript.exe`

Comment: jeb you're amazing that worked. I wonder why you need the Call in the FOR loop and everything works fine, but omitting it makes the FOR loop split the path. It doesn't happen that way if you aren't in the FOR loop. Can't believe I didn't try this way.

Comment: Some time ago, I learned it here [SO:FOR /F doesn't work if path has spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6474738/463115), there is also an explanation of the problem. But I remember there was an even simpler way to work with spaces but I can't find it anymore

Comment: @jeb, so it really has nothing to do with spaces.  It is the two sets of double quotes that causes the problem.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `@` instead of `CALL`. The trick is to prevent the command token from beginning with a double quote `"`. So both `@` and `CALL` will serve the same purpose here, but `CALL` has some potential side effects which `@` does not have. For instance if the quoted path to the executable contains the caret `^` then using `CALL` leads to failure. `@` is safer and faster than `CALL` and has no side effects: `@"%thePath%"MyScript.exe`

Comment: Tried the @ symbol trick and it worked. So to be clear, the problem is that inside the IN clause, because I have more than 2 double quotes, its removing the first and last ones and causing an issue, so putting anything that works before that solves the problem? That seems like a really odd behavior. Is it to prevent 'commands' from running as strings by removing the first and last double quote? I'd love to know why that happens. I'm sure theres a reason but I can't see it. Still, Fascinating effects. I'd love to thank y'all for your help, if you want, the comments would make a great answer.

Comment: With `for /F ... ('command')` the `command` inside the IN clause will be executed in a child cmd instance by invoking `cmd /c command`. It is the child cmd that is responsible for removing the quotes. The exact rules which cmd uses for processing the command line quotes are described in cmd command line help: `CMD /?`

Comment: Wow, that actually makes perfect sense then because running a raw string with double quotes as a command would never work to begin with. Interesting they chose child processes to do the work of iteration. I wonder what spurred that design choice.  It seems simple, but it works, simply make a child program execute the FOR loop code for each iteration normally and do it however many times it needs to. Thanks for the clarifying it makes so much more sense now.

Comment: Actually the loop iteration will be done in the main cmd instance. Here is how it works: the main cmd invokes a child instance passing the `command` of IN clause to it by `cmd /c command`. The `command` will be carried by the child cmd, and the main cmd captures all of the output from the child cmd and any processes that was invoked by child cmd. After the child cmd have finished its work and exited, the main cmd starts to iterate and execute be body of the `FOR` loop with the gathered data.

Comment: Now back to main issue, the problem you saw lies in `cmd /c command`.Forget about the FOR loops. Take this as example `cmd /c "echo hi & echo bye"` the `/C` switch tells cmd that execute everything that comes after `/C` then exit. Now it sees `"echo hi & echo bye"` as the command to execute. It first removes first an last quote then executes `echo hi & echo bye`. Now Take another example `cmd /c "C:\MyProg.exe"` this time it will NOT remove the quotes but execute it as is `"C:\MyProg.exe"`. So how cmd decides when to remove the quotes and when to keep them? Read `CMD /?` carefully to find out.