# Assign command output to variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, flash, cmd, registry

I'm trying to assign the output of a command to a variable - as in, I'm trying to set the current flash version to a variable. I know this is wrong, but this is what I've tried:

```
set var=reg query hklm\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\CurrentVersion>
```

or

```
reg query hklm\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\CurrentVersion >> set var
```

Yeah, as you can see I'm a bit lost. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: If the below answers didn't help, search redirection on google.

Comment: Actually the original seems to be [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/108439/12892).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

A method has already been devised, however this way you don't need a temp file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('command') do set output=%%i
```

However, I'm sure this has its own exceptions and limitations.

Comment: I get `%%i was unexpected at this time.` as result when I execute above command. Not sure why.

Comment: @JoelHandwell if you are using this on the command line, you should only use one %. Ex: `for /f "delims=" %i in ('command') do set output=%i`

Comment: Using the statement in a batch file, if `command` has a pipe (|) then it errors out with: "| was unexpected at this time."  Can someone help with the syntax, please?

Comment: Like this the return value aka **ERRORLEVEL** gets lost.
Anyone an idea how to preserve or obtain this?

Comment: If you're trying to catch the error value, u need to redirect it to standard out in your command section.  so if the command is: 
"dir"
Then you'll need to append "2>&1"onto the end like this "dir 2>&1"

Comment: Not sure why, but instead of `do set` I had to do `do CALL set`

Answer (score 14):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks) has a method to achieve this

> from (zvrba)
>   You can do it by redirecting the output to a file first. For example:

```
echo zz > bla.txt
set /p VV=<bla.txt
echo %VV%
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign a process output directly into a var, you need to parse the output with a For /F loop:

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN (
    'Reg Query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" /v "CurrentVersion"'
) DO (
    REM Set "Version=%%B"
    Echo Version: %%B
)

Pause&Exit
```

http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

PS: Change the reg key used if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Okay here some more complex sample for the use of **For /F**

```
:: Main
@prompt -$G
    call :REGQUERY  "Software\Classes\CLSID\{3E6AE265-3382-A429-56D1-BB2B4D1D}"

@goto :EOF

:REGQUERY
:: Checks HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ 
:: for the key and lists its content

    @call :EXEC "REG QUERY  HKCU\%~1"
    @call :EXEC "REG QUERY "HKLM\%~1""

@goto :EOF    

:EXEC
    @set output=

    @for /F "delims=" %%i in ('%~1 2^>nul') do @(
        set output=%%i
    )

    @if not "%output%"=="" (
        echo %1 -^> %output%
    )

@goto :EOF
```

I packed it into the sub function **:EXEC** so all of its nasty details of implementation doesn't litters the main script.
So it got some kinda some batch tutorial.
Notes 'bout the code:

1. the output from the command executed via **call :EXEC *command*** is stored in **%output%**. *Batch cmd doesn't cares about scopes so %output% will be also available in the main script.*
2. the **@** the beginning is just decoration and there to suppress echoing the command line. You may delete them all and just put some **@echo off** at the first line is really dislike that. However like this I find debugging much more nice. 
   Decoration Number two is **prompt -$G**. It's there to make command prompt look like this **->**
3. I use **::** instead of **rem**
4. the tilde(~) in **%~1** is to remove quotes from the first argument
5. **2^>nul** is there to suppress/discard *stderr* error output. Normally you would do it via **2>nul**. Well the **^** the batch escape char is there avoids to early resolving the redirector(>). There's some simulare use a little later in the script: `echo %1 -^>...` so there ^ makes it possible the output a '>' via echo what else wouldn't have been possible.
6. even if the compare at `@if not "%output%"==""`looks like in most common programming languages - it's maybe different that you expected (if you're not used to MS-batch). Well remove the '@' at the beginning. Study the output. Change it to`not %output%==""`-rerun and consider why this doesn't work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me

```
@FOR /f "delims=" %i in ('reg query hklm\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\CurrentVersion') DO set var=%i
echo %var%
```

Comment: it seems one percent sign (`%`) works only on command line, and in the batch file you should use double them (`%%`)