# Batch - Assign Command output with variables to Variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I am looking for way to assign output of a command to a batch variable, but the command internally uses another variable.

When i use the solution specified in 
[Assign Command output to Variable in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)

I am getting error that the variable inside the command was not expected at this time.

Please help

Comment: It would help to know what command you're trying to use, and exactly how it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.

Say you command was `Echo hi` and you wanted to store the output (`'hi'`) into a variable:

```
Echo hi > out.tmp
set /p var=< out.tmp
del out.tmp

Echo %var%
```

where var now stores the value of your output. Note: it will only store the first the line of output. If you want to do last line of output comment and I would make it use a for loop instead.