# Sending Windows Battch command output to variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the following in a Windows batch file

```
my_app < "%%PARAMETER_FOR_APP"
```

The application executes succesfully, and outputs three lines to the console.

I want to capture that output so as to be able to save it to a log file.

I am trying this:

```
set LOG_FILE_NAME = mylog.log
my_app < "%%PARAMETER_FOR_APP" > COMMAND_OUTPUT
echo %COMMAND_OUTPUT%
echo %COMMAND_OUTPUT% >> %LOG_FILE_NAME%
```

I am expecting a variable, `COMMAND_OUTPUT`, to be created, which I can then use with the eccho command. But instead an *empty file*, `COMMAND_OUTPUT`, is created on the file system.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is LOG_FILE_NAME set to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Assign Command output to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)

Answer (score 0):

[FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) is the standard way to get command output in batch file.
In your case you also need to escape the redirection with `^`

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('my_app ^< "%%PARAMETER_FOR_APP" ') do set "COMMAND_OUTPUT=%%#"
```

try this.

Comment: Might benefit from a little more expansion as to what's going on.