# Trying to set the outcome of a function to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

When i try to run this program it does not set the variable right. Is there anyway so that after it is done to set the file location not the file itself to a variable and have it printed on screen.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (d) do if exist "%%a:\" dir /b /s /a-d "%%a:\gm_construct.bsp" set p=%%~dpnxa
pause
```

Comment: Which variable is not being set right? What is it currently being set to, and what do you want it to be set to?

Comment: The variable p in the above code. When i try to use it other places in my code it doen't work. I want it set to the file location not the file but not sure how to do that exactly and I have no idea what it is being set to.

Comment: So you want to set it to the output of the `dir` command? Have you tested that all other parts of the code work (i.e. it actually runs the `dir` command when it finds the file)?

Comment: Did you ever think of searching through SO? there are numerous of questions like this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Assign Command output to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code does:

```
dir /b /s /a-d "%%a:\gm_construct.bsp" set p=%%~dpnxa
```

lists all files `"%%a:\gm_construct.bsp"` and all files named `set` and all files named `p=%%~dpnxa`

What (I think) you want to do:

```
dir /b /s /a-d "%%a:\gm_construct.bsp"
```

and set it's output to the variable `%p%`

To get a command's output, you need another `for`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%a:\gm_construct.bsp"') do set p=%%~dpnxi
```

integrated into your code (note the kind of the single quotes: `'`):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (d) do (
  if exist "%%a:\" (
     for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%a:\gm_construct.bsp"') do set p=%%~dpnxi
  )
)
pause
```

pause

Comment: That works except that it gives the file name after the path i only want it set to the folder that it is in any help.

Comment: `%~dpnxi` means **d**rive, **p**ath, **n**ame and e**x**tension of `%%i`. So you probably want `%%~dpi`

Comment: Thank you i should of thought of that. I spent 2 hours trying to figure that out.