# how to store value of key in a variable (for Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, key

I want to store a value of key in a variable. i solved problem like this in linux using

```
var1=`cat /path/to/file1.txt | grep -i "no3" | cut -d '=' -f2`
```

now i want to store a key's value in variable in windows machine.

Comment: You want to do something like that on Windows?? Good luck then!

Answer (score 0):

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable).Though you need to escape some special characters:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (`cat /path/to/file1.txt ^| grep -i "no3" ^| cut -d '^=' -f2`) do (
  set "var1=%%#"
)
```