# Bat File to Parse XML

Tags: xml, parsing, batch-file, command

If I have xml file with following format, how do I parse it in batch(.bat) script? or is there a way I can only get certain value without parsing it?

For example, I need to get the value of 'date' from this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<slideshow 
    title="Sample Slide Show"
    date="2016/05/03"
    author="Yours Truly"  >

</slideshow>
</note>
```

Comment: Pure batch scripting is not capable of parsing XML files; I recommend to use a language that supports XML natively (PowerShell, VBScript, JavaScript, etc.?); if you do want a batch file for this, you could even embed another language; if you do not want this either, you need to read the XML file as normal text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution. The following script expects three command line arguments: the (path to the) XML file, the node (`slideshow` in your example) and the attribute name (`date`), in the given order. The return data is output to the console window and can be redirected into a file (`>`).

This is a sample command line to run the script (supposing the XML file is called `presentation.xml`, the script is named `extract-xml-attrib.bat` and the resulting data are to be written to `attr.txt`):

```
"extract-xml-attrib.bat" "presentation.xml" "slideshow" "date" > "attr.txt"
```

This is the code of the script `extract-xml-attrib.bat`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "XML=%~1"
set "TAG=%~2"
set "PAR=%~3"

rem // Define defaults here:
if not defined XML set "XML=presentation.xml"
if not defined TAG set "TAG=slideshow"
if not defined PAR set "PAR=date"

set "FLAG="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%XML%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG%=!"
    if not defined REST (
        set "FLAG=#"
    ) else (
        set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG% =!"
        if not "!REST!"=="!LINE!" (
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG% =!"
            if not "!REST!"=="!LINE!" (
                set "FLAG=#"
            )
        )
    )
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=>" %%E in ("!REST!/") do (
        if defined FLAG (
            endlocal
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
        set "REST=%%E"
        if defined FLAG (
            call :GET_ATTR "REST:~,-1" "%PAR%"
        )
        if not "%%F"=="" (
            set "FLAG="
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:GET_ATTR var_string param_name
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "PAR=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~1!"
set "NEXT="
for %%S in (!STR!) do (
    if defined NEXT (
        endlocal
        echo(%%~S
        set "NEXT="
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    set "STR=!STR:*%%S=!"
    if "%%S"=="%PAR%" (
        if defined STR (
            if "!STR:~,1!"=="=" (
                if "!STR:~1,1!"==" " (
                    echo(
                ) else if "!STR:~1,1!"=="   " (
                    echo(
                ) else (
                    set "NEXT=#"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
if defined NEXT echo(
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that accepts a single argument - the xml file and gets slideshow's node date attribute value. You can alter the xpath query to fits your needs if the file has different structure:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    rem :: the first argument is the script name as it will be used for proper help message
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var objDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
objDoc.load(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

var objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//slideshow");
WScript.Echo(objNode.getAttribute("date"));
```

**EDIT**
here's a [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) now - a script for common usage that can parse a xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works well. I am curious whether i can use the value of 'date' as parameter run another bat script?

Comment: yes you can - [just call the batch file with for command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)