# Parsing XML for tag attributes in Windows batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, command

I've search continuously for this.  And seen quite a few SO pages on this but none of them seem to be working for me.  Many of them have tokens which I can't use because my attribute "filename" could be anywhere in the tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<thisprog>
<sessions>
    <main>
        <File fvl="0" offst="0" filename="c:\here\there.txt" backupFilePath="" />
        <File filename="c:\here\there2.txt" mapWrapIndentMode="-1" wrappie="no" />
        <File wrapCount="1" filename="c:\here\folder1\oops.txt" wrappie="no" />
        <File lang="None" encd="-1" ro="no" filename="c:\here\folder 2\foop.txt" />
    </main>
</sessions>
</thisprog>
```

I'm trying to get the batch to get the "filename" attributes and concatenate them together.  So end up with (and with the quotes, since they are directories and could have spaces):

```
"c:\here\there.txt" "c:\here\there2.txt" "c:\here\folder1\oops.txt" "c:\here\folder 2\foop.txt"
```

I tried the code here [Attribute ripping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37040138/1913845) but I am not able to concatenate the filename strings.  I must be missing something.

```bash
@echo off&setlocal

@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "XML=%~1"
set "TAG=%~2"
set "PAR=%~3"
set "ALLFILES="

rem // Define defaults here:
if not defined XML set "XML=presentation.xml"
if not defined TAG set "TAG=slideshow"
if not defined PAR set "PAR=date"

set "FLAG="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%XML%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG%=!"
    if not defined REST (
        set "FLAG=#"
    ) else (
        set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG% =!"
        if not "!REST!"=="!LINE!" (
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            set "REST=!LINE:*<%TAG% =!"
            if not "!REST!"=="!LINE!" (
                set "FLAG=#"
            )
        )
    )
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=>" %%E in ("!REST!/") do (
        if defined FLAG (
            endlocal
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
        set "REST=%%E"
        if defined FLAG (
            call :GET_ATTR "REST:~,-1" "%PAR%"
        )
        if not "%%F"=="" (
            set "FLAG="
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)
echo "the end"
echo %ALLFILES%
endlocal
exit /B


:GET_ATTR var_string param_name
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "PAR=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~1!"
set "ALLFILESFUNC=%%~S "
set "NEXT="
for %%S in (!STR!) do (
    if defined NEXT (
        endlocal
        echo the filename - "%%~S"
        rem //This is the filename attribute but I can't get it to concatenate to an accumulative string
        rem echo(%%~S
        set "NEXT="
        rem //It's not collecting the strings.
        set "ALLFILESFUNC=!ALLFILESFUNC! "^%%~S"^ "
        echo Accumulative - %ALLFILESFUNC%
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    set "STR=!STR:*%%S=!"
    if "%%S"=="%PAR%" (
        if defined STR (
            if "!STR:~,1!"=="=" (
                if "!STR:~1,1!"==" " (
                    echo(
                ) else if "!STR:~1,1!"=="   " (
                    echo(
                ) else (
                    set "NEXT=#"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
if defined NEXT echo(
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated: I have it getting the filename but I won't collect all the filenames into one variable, ALLFILESFUNC.

Comment: Why not to use Powershell for the task?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky , constraints.

Comment: My sympathies.  Trying to parse XML in Windows Batch is like trying to make fine furniture with primitive stone tools.

Comment: Microsoft made a tool to parse XML files as well.  MSXSL.  Used it in several batch files in the past.

Comment: Why do you have exclamations around the `FOR` variable? `set "ALLFILES=!ALLFILES! !%%S! "`

Comment: @Squashman , I am still a novice at this.  So I was trying different things out.  What should I do?

Comment: Maybe remove the exclamations!

Comment: Done.  I updated it above.  I feel like it's almost there.  It's just not collecting all the filenames.

Comment: Variables in batch have a size limit. You can only squeeze a certain amount of file names (characters) into it.

Comment: @Squashman , I looked into the msxsl but the script has to be a wbt file.  How do you run those?!

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.  All I ever needed was the Input.xml, an XSL file to tell the program what you want from the XML file and msxsl.exe.

Comment: @Squashman , apparently, msxsl or xslt doesn't come in Windows 10.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182035/where-is-msxsl-exe

Comment: If you search hard enough you can still find the executable to download.  Microsoft has removed the direct download of the exe from their site.  It runs find on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid I don't understand your code...

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "AllFiles="
(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr "filename=" test.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in (^"!line:" ="^

!^") do set %%c
   set "AllFiles=!AllFiles! !filename!"
)) 2> NUL
echo AllFiles=%AllFiles%
```

Output:

```
AllFiles= "c:\here\there.txt" "c:\here\there2.txt" "c:\here\folder1\oops.txt" "c:\here\folder 2\foop.txt"
```