# How to get the FIND command output count value into a variable in batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using a command:

```
find /c "abc" "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\project\string.txt"
```

Output:

> ```
> ---------- C:\Users\abc\Desktop\project\string.txt: 4
> ```

I want to assign this value `4` to a variable so that I can use it for an `if` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Batch - Assign Command output to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
For /F %%A In ('Find /C "abc"^<"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\project\string.txt"') Do (
    Set "mlc=%%A")
```

Your %mlc% varaiable would hold the matched line count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best method to do this, but it works:

```
find /c "abc" "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\project\string.txt" > tmpFile 
set /p myvar= < tmpFile 
del tmpFile
```

Answer (score 0):

with your snytax the output is `---------- C:\Users\abc\Desktop\project\string.txt: 4`
There is another syntax: `type file.txt|find /c "abc"`, which gives you a beautiful output of just:

```
15
```

To get it into a variable, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f %%a in ('type file.txt^|find /c "abc"') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

(for use directly on commandline (not in a batchfile) use `%a` instead of `%%a`)

Comment: by using "type file.txt|find /c "abc"" this command the text file gets open and also the count displays 0.

Comment: i want to get the count value and compare with the actual count so that i get the output as pass or fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a batch script / Windows command line pro, but I got this to work with the following, **without a temporary file**:

```sh
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%~dpSomeFolder\*.suffix" /b ^|find /c "suffix"') do set "fileCount=%%a"
```

Explanation:

1. I found it very confusing, why assigning a variable with a batch script, is so weird, considering it's "Windows", the most used operating system. Anyways this answer here is helpful. Even if it is a duplicate, I like the formatting more:
   [Assign command output to variable in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/assign-command-output-to-variable-in-batch-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. **%~dp0**: basically translates to "path of this script". You can find info about this online.
3. **SomeFolder\*.suffix**: In my case this I was looking to count the number of files ending with a certain suffix. I had problems using the **dir** command with **\s** as this listed all the matches in subfolders I did not expect him too look. As if this was referenced to the path from which I executed this script from. Therefore, the path name with the asterisk "\*****.suffix" solved that issue for me.
4. **^|**: When using the pipe sign "|" in "for command", specified inside the single quotation marks, **you need to use a circumflex "^|"**, instead of just the "|", which you would normally use when just typing in the command in cmd (f.e. like dir "%~dp0Folder*.suffix" /b | find /c "suffix"
5. **%%a**: You have to use the "double percentage", as this is just a locale variable when writing this in a batch script.

FYI: you can have a look at the command help/ manual ("man" as I am used to Linux), with the command /? (f.e. dir /? or find /?)

I thought I would also mention how I then used this variable, as this might save some time for you ;) (batch code coloring somehow did not work here...).

```sh
IF %fileCount% NEQ 1 (ECHO Number of SUFFIX files does not equal 1! Found %fileCount% SUFFIX files inside the SomeFolder. Aborting script! & PAUSE & EXIT)
```