# How to pass dynamically generated string to program as an argument in Windows cmd?

Tags: python, linux, windows, batch-file, cmd

In Linux bash I could pass python-printed string as a parameter to my program and it looked like this `my_program $(python -c "print('A'*100)")`

Is there a way to do the same in Windows CMD?

Comment: No, but you can run the python program from a `for /f` loop and parse the output. If `A` represents a variable from the batch it should be written `%A%`

Comment: Is `'A'*100500` a real example? See [What is the maximum length of an environment variable?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100203-00/?p=15083)

Comment: @JosefZ just fixed that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Assign Command output to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable)

Comment: A batch `for /f` loop executes the loop body for every line in the file or command output, but bash instead collapses white space (spaces, tabs, newlines) in the output to a space-delimited string in which quotes are literals. To approximate this in cmd, you could join lines with spaces, e.g. `set "args="` `& (for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (\`python -c "print('A\n' * 100)"\`)` `do @(if defined args (set "args=!args! %i") else (set args=%i)))` `& my_program !args!`. But this doesn't translate tabs to spaces or escape double quotes as literals.

Comment: @eryksun thanks. That helped