# Parse a dynamically sized string

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a variable:

```
set myvar="26:deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.8.0_111"
```

I want to retrieve the value after the jre. and .product which would be the integer 0. The value in between here will always be an integer. The variable can string can change slightly, but the format of [jre.][integer][.product] will always stay the same. Because of this I cant just get the substring using hardcoded values because the string may be different each time and have more characters at the beginning if say the first digit at the beginning of the string is 3 digits instead of 2 long. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=:." %%a in ("%myvar%") do echo -%%a-
```

try this

Answer (score 3):

In case the number of dots (and colons) in front of the `jre.` part may vary, you could use this:

```bat
set "myvar=26:deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.8.0_111"

rem // Split off everything up to `jre.` (case-insensitive search):
set "integer=%myvar:*jre.=%"
rem /* Convert remaining portion to a signed 32-bit integer
rem    (everything up to the `.` in `.product` is regarded): */
set /A "integer=integer"

echo %integer%
```