# How to store the results from my query into a variable in a batch file?

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I have a script getCount.sql that I use to extract the count of records from the table. the query is as below.

---

```
connect user/pwd@DB
spool C:\filepath\filename.txt

select count(distinct(column name)) 
from table name 
where condition
/

spool off
exit;
```

---

I call this from getCount.bat file using the command

```
sqlplus /nolog @C:\filepath\getCount.sql
```

I am able to get the output into the file filename.txt. I need assistance to store this into a variable in the getCount.bat batch file and use it for further computing.

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (´sqlplus /nolog @C:\filepath\getCount.sql´) do set "yourVar=%%a"`. See `for /?` for more help in parsing whatever the output of this command may be.

Comment: Please show the output of this command, that is the content of `C:\filepath\filename.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign Command output to Variable in Batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/assign-command-output-to-variable-in-batch-file)

Comment: @Magoo - the result looks as below. I need to check if the result holds a value greater than 0 and perform my next set of actions based on this. 

COUNT(COLUMN NAME)                                             
----------------------------------                                              
                                 1

Comment: Please edit this data into your question as it's not possible to tell the exact format of the data in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable of type Number, select count into that variable:

```
connect user/pwd@DB
spool C:\filepath\filename.txt

   Declare MyNumber Number;
BEGIN
    select count(distinct(Column_Name)) 
    into MyNumber
    from table_name
    where condition;
    IF MyNumber > 0 THEN
        -- Do Stuff Here ....
    END IF;
END;
/
spool off
exit;
```

Comment: We were unable to run the above modified query. What i would need to be able to do is compare the result of the query (the count from the query) and if it is greater than 0, i need to run the next query.

Comment: My bad, I shouldn't write code off the top of my head.  I modified my answer above.

Comment: In the above query ,we need to call another batch file inside the IF statement. Could you please help us out with this?

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to shell out from the procedure?  Assuming that the code you want to run is PL/Sql code, just run the code you want from within the If statement.  Or is there a specific operating system thing you need to do?

Comment: In the above code, if the variable #MyNumber >0 then it should call another the other batch file, which consists of another Sql Query.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use SQL to create a new .bat file and then run that.

Answer (score 0):

just change the file extension of file. The result will be save in .bat file

connect user/pwd@DB
spool C:\filepath\filename.bat

select count(distinct(column name)) 
from table name 
where condition
/

spool off
exit;