# assign adb output to a variable in batch script

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, adb

im using adb shell commands to check if my devices' screen is on or not

```
adb shell dumpsys power | find "mWakefulness="
```

if the screen is off this command returns `mWakefulness=Asleep`

what i want to do is assign the output of that command to a variable and run it through an if statement to check if `mWakefulness=Asleep`

ive tried this

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell dumpsys power | find "mWakefulness="') do (
    Set "Output=%%a"
)
Echo Output Result = "%OutPut%"
```

but this returns `| was unexpected at this time.`

so i tried to surround `adb shell dumpsys power | find "mWakefulness="` with double quotes

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"adb shell dumpsys power | find "mWakefulness=""') do (
    Set "Output=%%a"
)
Echo Output Result = "%OutPut%"
```

but this returns `Output Result = ""`

can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign command output to variable in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/assign-command-output-to-variable-in-batch-file)

Comment: With the additional double-quotes the `=`-sign appears unquoted to the parser, hence you need to escape it like `^=`…

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you need to "escape" the `|` by preceding it with a caret (`^`).

This tells batch that the pipe is part of the command-to-be-executed, not the `FOR` statement