# Get value returned by uuidgen.exe in batch file

Tags: windows, winapi, batch-file, guid

How would I get this code to store the value returned by `uuidgen.exe`? I want the value of `guid` to be a `Guid`, not the path to `uuidgen.exe`.

```
SET guid="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\uuidgen.exe"
ECHO %guid%
pause
```

Comment: `\\servername\network share\path to\file.exe`

Comment: @Endoro How does that answer my question?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a batch file you need the double percent sign on your variables, and to properly quote the path to uuidgen.exe.
The following works in a batch file on my local computer (note the different version of SDK)

```
for /f %%i in ('"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\uuidgen.exe"') do set guid=%%i
echo %guid%
```