# How to get the ruby.exe Return Code in CMD Bat?

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get the return value of a ruby script in cmd.exe. The ruby script will return -1 if exception is caught and 0 if success.

```
rescue Exception => ex
  puts ex.message
  returnvalue = -1
else
  returnvalue = 0
ensure
  puts returnvalue
```

in the cmd batch, calling the script using ruby.exe

```
ruby tt.rb 1 %1
```

But I'm not able to retreive the returnvalue in the cmd batch file (e.g. using %errorlevel%). Is there any way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: Do not exit with a negative value. Exit with 0 on success and a value greater 0 on error. Microsoft strongly recommends not returning a negative value. Also on Linux/Unix no negative value should be returned on exit by an application or script for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts -1` does not make `ruby.exe` return `-1`; it makes it *print* `-1`. It *returns* `-1` if you do `exit -1`.

In *nix, it is easy to capture the *output* (as opposed to the exit code) of the program into a variable. Under Windows, not so easy; there is a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows) you can do involving the `for` construct, but it is of limited use.