# Redirect Powershell output available to command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I was wondering how to make available powershell variable in order to be read from the command line. Is that possible?

The command is

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | Select -Expand macaddress -Last 1 | set-variable -name mac1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't Powershell in DOS, so I'd guess you have a CMD script (i.e. a .bat or .cmd file) that needs to assign a variable returned from Powershell. This is [suprisingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108439/503046) quite [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2323292/503046).

```
C:\>for /f "delims=" %i in ('powershell -command " & {  get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter 'netconnectionstatus
= 2' | Select -Expand macaddress -Last 1 } "') do set foobar=%i

C:\>set foobar=00:19:99:E1:98:32

C:\>echo %foobar%
00:19:99:E1:98:32
```