# How to return a string value from a Delphi application as output parameter

Tags: delphi, batch-file, parameter-passing, delphi-2009

I have a small Delphi 2009-application that serves as a way to call some SQL procedures and do some background work.

It can be called with a path to a text file containing a SQL statement as input parameter and executes it.

Now I want the Delphi-application to return an output value, a string.

I found how to deal with output values when calling applications from a batch file ([How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)), but I don't know how to fill this value from within Delphi. Where in Delphi do I assign my string value to some kind of output parameter, so the calling batch file can use the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it to the standard output:

```
Writeln(MyOutputText);
```

Comment: ... so a batch file can capture that standard output and process it, for instance using pipes.

Comment: Ok thanks both, for the comments. I'll try that. Although I don't understand why my question needs to be downvoted two times...is it that stupid?