# How to set variable to output of for loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am reading a text file %tmp%\tmp.txt. I am trying to find a line with a given string (in this example "RemotePath") and it sets the variable netdrive to that line if it is found. Here is my code:

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%tmp%\tmp.txt) do echo.%%a|findstr /C:"RemotePath " >nul 2>&1 && set netdrive=%%a`

It never sets netdrive to anything, however when i change the `set netdrive=%%a` to `echo %%a >> netdrive.txt` the text I want does come up in the text file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /C:"RemotePath " "%tmp%\tmp.txt"') do set "netdrive=%%a"
```

The "problem" with the original code is that each side of a pipe is executed in a separate process, so, in your case, the `set` command is running in another `cmd` instance and the variable is set in this separate instance, not in the instance that runs the batch file.

Comment: Interesting. I tried this and I run into the error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." I checked and %tmp%\tmp.txt does exist. The file starts with an empty line. The second line contains a reg key path. The third line starts with a tab, and then says RemotePath blah blah blah (the line that I want to set to the variable netdrive. When I run the command within the parenthesis `findstr /C:"RemotePath " "%tmp%\tmp.txt"` it outputs the correct line to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jordan, sorry, my fault. There was a typo error, a quote placed where it shouldn't be. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are repeatedly setting `netdrive` to each `token` from the input file, *not* the output of `findstr`. The final assignment probably gives it an empty value from the end of the file. To assign it from the output of `findstr`, see here: [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

Comment: I tried this `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%tmp%\tmp.txt) do (
echo %%a | findstr /c:"RemotePath" 
if errorlevel 0 set netdrive=%%a
)` but got the same result. Am I still setting netdrive to %%a to every line?

Comment: %%a is always the latest token. I don't know about the return code of findstr so can't speculate on that.