# Assign expression value in windows script

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, expression

I searched answer on my question, but just found [some complex scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows).

I'm trying to configure some software. I have *.cmd file with expression:

```
SET SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH={hadoop classpath}
```

But using just brackets around expression I can't get result as concatenated paths with libs. In Linux, I can replace this expression with

```
EXPORT SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=${hadoop classpath}
```

and all works fine.

Is it possible to achive the same behaviuor from Windows script in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SET SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=%hadoop classpath%
```

Although, I am not sure if the space is tolerated in the name of the environmental variable. A convention is to use capital letters and an underscore.

Comment: `hadoop classpath` isn't a varible. It's command which execution result is string. Your variant doesn't work