# Save the result of a command in variable, Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, set

I am trying to write a batch script that saves the result of a command in a variable. so I can use it later.

For example I am tryin to run this on the script:
sc queryex "Service" |find /i "pid"

but I want to save this result in a variable.

```
set PIDRS=sc queryex "Themes" |find /i "pid"
ECHO "%PIDRS%
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have a look here...http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('sc queryex "Themes" ^|find /i "pid"') do set "PIDRS=%%#"
echo %PIDRS%
```

This will set the entire line to `PIDRS`

here's how to get only the pid:

```
@echo off

set "rspid="
for /f "skip=9 tokens=2 delims=:" %%# in ('sc queryex "Themes"') do (
  if not defined rspid set /a rspid=%%#
)
```

the second does not use additional FIND which in theory should make it faster.

Comment: `skip=9` fails for a stopped service, leads to `Missing operand` error. I'd use (from command line) `for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %# in ('sc queryex "Themes"') do @if /I "%#"=="PID" set /A "rspid=%$"`

Comment: @eranotzap it will be assigned to variable `rspid`.You can get its value with `%rspid%`