# How do I add a variable to a file name in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I want to redirect a file to a text file with a specific filename. The filename should be the serial number of the machine. I currently have the below command but for some reason, the output is different from what I want.

```
@echo off
set serial=wmic bios get serialnumber
set bit=manage-bde -status C:
%bit% > "C:\Users\Frangon\Desktop\%serial%.txt"
pause
```

It redirects the `%bit%` to a text file but the filename becomes `wmic bios get serialnumber` instead of the SERIAL NUMBER of the machine.

Please help as I'm stuck.

Comment: You've set a variable to a string value, not a command result. To save the variable as a command result you'll need a `For /F` loop. There are hundreds of examples of this on the site, please search.

Comment: Would you please direct me Compo? Thank you sir.

Comment: From the site search, _at the top of the page_, the top result from, `[batch-file]save result command variable`, will be a possible duplicate i.e. [Save the result of a command in variable, Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215819/save-the-result-of-a-command-in-variable-windows-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment before, the way to get a command's output to a variable is a `for /f` loop. There is one quirk with `wmic`: it has unusual line endings `CR CR LF`. The first `CR` will be part of the variable and will cause bad things. One way to overcome that (and the most reliable way) is parsing the output with another `for` loop.

There is no need to assign the output of `manage-bde -status C:` to a variable (would be very difficult in batch anyway because it's more than one line). Just redirect the output directly to the file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do for %%b in (%%a) do set "serial=%%b"
manage-bde -status C: > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%serial%.txt"
```