# batch command output to variable as text

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
cscript //nologo versioninfo.vbs Kernel Kernel\bin\Release\Kernel.exe
```

This script returns me a version of my Kernel file. Let's say 3.11

Now I want to create a directory containing that 3.11.

```
set version=cscript //nologo versioninfo.vbs Kernel Kernel\bin\Release\Kernel.exe

set destination=\MyProgram(%version%)

if not exist %destination% mkdir %destination%
```

but it doesn't create it with the name

> MyProgram(3.11)

as expected but creates as

> MyProgram(cscript //nologo versioninfo.vbs Kernel
>   Kernel\bin\Release\Kernel.exe)

So I need my cscript output set as a text so I could just insert it into my destination.

Solution:

```
cscript //nologo versioninfo.vbs Kernel Kernel\bin\Release\Kernel.exe > tmp
SET /p version= < tmp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

cscript //nologo versioninfo.vbs Kernel Kernel\bin\Release\Kernel.exe > tmp
SET /p version= < tmp