# What does the output " Usage: adb devices [-l] " means?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

According to [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

Changing the command from `date` to `adb devices`, the output becomes weird.

Here is my code

```
@echo OFF 
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('adb devices /t') DO set today=%%i
echo %today%
pause
```

Output:

`Usage: adb devices [-l]`

Try in another way

```
@echo OFF
set adbstart=C:\Users\kuanlinchen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('call %adbstart% /t') DO set today=%%i
echo %today%
pause
```

Also output:

`Usage: adb devices [-l]`

If I run `adb devices` in this way, works fine.

```
@echo OFF
adb devices
pause
```

Output:

```
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXXXXXX    device
```

**What does the weird output `Usage: adb devices [-l]` means ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adb devices` command does not have the `/t` parameter. In case of an invalid parameter error `adb` shows its proper *usage* message.