# Get result of command with quoted arguments within single quote command evaluation in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**How do you pass quoted arguments to an executable in a single-quoted evaluation** such as `FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces"') do ...`**?**

As per many of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows), I'm trying to use the output of a console app in a Windows batch script, using the *single quotes* to get the console to evaluate it.
However, I need to quote some of the arguments I want to pass to that executable, which *also* needs to be quoted, as the path contains spaces as well.
But when I do that, the quoting around the executable path breaks.

Here is the would-be line:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!PathToExe!" action^=sanitize string^="!album!"') DO set "falbum=%%i"
```

(Both *!PathToExe!* and *!album!* contain spaces. It seems like I need to escape the equal signs here, hence the circumflexes. Delayed expansion is *on*)

The above results in "**Outcome A**": Quoting is broken for the exe path

> '<Part of path to exe>' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've tried different combinations of different quote usages and escapings, but haven't found a way to make it work.

### Here are some attempts and their results:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!PathToExe!" action^=sanitize string^=!album!') DO set "falbum=%%i")
```

No quotes around *!album!* results in "**Outcome B**": As expected, only the first word gets passed along with *string=*, all the other words get scattered as individual arguments.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!PathToExe!" action^=sanitize string^=^"!album!^"') DO set "falbum=%%i")
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('^"!PathToExe!^" action^=sanitize string^=^"!album!^"') DO set "falbum=%%i")
```

Trying to escape the quotes for the *string=* argument or both exe path and string arg: **Outcome A** (still breaks the quoting for the exe path, gives:)

> '<Part of path to exe>' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!PathToExe!" action^=sanitize string^=^'!album!^'') DO set "falbum=%%i")
```

Using escaped single quotes: **Outcome B** again

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!PathToExe!" action^=sanitize string^='"!album!") DO set "falbum=%%i")
```

Ending the single quote before the *string=* value and simply having it in quotes after that seems to result in *everything* being taken as a single first argument (command/path):

> The system cannot find the file '"<path to exe>" action=sanitize string='"<Album var with spaces and whatnot>".

It does not matter whether the quotes are part of the variables or literally typed in the `IN ('...')` line.

### Simple testing:

You could test this behavior if you copied `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` to a directory with spaces, e.g. `C:\folder with spaces\` and pasted the following script there:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set PathToExe="%~dp0cmd.exe"
REM Toggle the next line to compare between quoted path with spaces and path without quotes or spaces:
REM set PathToExe=cmd.exe
set string=%~dp0

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('!PathToExe! /C CD C:\windows\system32 ^& dir !string!') DO set "fstring=%%i"
echo !fstring!
pause
```

This should illustrate the challenge of having two quoted sections in one statement.
If the *!string!* variable remains unquoted, you'll get "The system cannot find the file specified.".
If the quotes of the *!PathToExe!* variable break, you'll see something like "'C:\folder' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for /F` command, when used to capture and parse command output, actually uses `cmd /C` to execute that command, which handles quotation marks in a particular way. From its help (`cmd /?`):

> ```cmd
> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
>     1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>         - no /S switch
>         - exactly two quote characters
>         - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>           where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>         - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>           two quote characters
>         - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>           of an executable file.
>
>     2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.
> ```

This means that:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('"executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces"') do (…)
```

actually tries to execute the command line:

```cmd
cmd /C "executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces"
```

leading to:

```cmd
executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces
```

which is obviously invalid syntax.

To overcome this issue provide an additional pair of quotes:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('^""executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces"^"') do (…)
```

It is a good idea to escape these additional quotes (by `^"`), so there is no need to alter any potential escape sequences.

Comment: Ah! Thank you!! I didn't realize that `cmd /C "executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces"` leads to `executable path" arg1 "arg2 which contains spaces`! Somehow, I didn't think to try that combination ^^