# running perl program from C++ program

Tags: c++, perl

I have a C++ program to compute inventory and when it falls below a certain level I want to call my perl program that will write the order details into the DB.
I read the documentation on calling Perl from C++ and I was trying this sample code

```
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    char *args[] = { NULL };
    PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct(my_perl);
    perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, NULL);
    PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
    /*** skipping perl_run() ***/
    call_argv("showtime", G_DISCARD | G_NOARGS, args);
    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);
    PERL_SYS_TERM();
}
```

I tried to compile but I get the following error

```
g++ fn-test.cpp -o t 'perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts'
g++: perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts: No such file or directory
fn-test.cpp:2:24: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am working on ubuntu so I went into cpan and ran

```
force install ExtUtils::Embed
```

it did it's thing for a while and now when I try to compile again, I get the same error. 
This is my first time trying to call a Perl program from C++, so any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Is it necessary for you a high couple between Perl & C++ ? If not, you can do a system("perl myscript.pl")

Comment: that's how I run the perl program from the commandline...did you mean I do the same from within my C++ program

Comment: @itcplpl: Yes, but using the `system()` function from `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: just ran that and it gives me the following error Can't locate Date/Manip.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.15.2/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.15.2 .) I went into CPAN and ran force install Date::Manip, but it doesn't seem to work...any suggestions....I had it working before I ran the force install ExtUtils::Embed :-(

Comment: I get the following error >Building Date-Manip
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2/Date'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2/Date'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.15.2/Module/Build/Base.pm line 3574
  SBECK/Date-Manip-6.25.tar.gz
  ./Build install  -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 SBECK/Date-Manip-6.25.tar.gz                 : install NO

how do I give myself permission to my own computer

Comment: if you have privileges, yo need to do "sudo make install" when you are installing the Date::Manip package. Otherwise, yo can install your own perl (different from system perl) with perlbrew

Comment: You *do* have the perl headers installed, right?

Comment: well, I played around because I realized 5.15.2 was a development version (didn't know odd numbers were dev versions) and I now am unable to cpan and when I run a perl program I get the following error Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.15.2 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.15.2/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.15.2 .) at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 5.
I don't believe my system perl is affected or is it?

Answer (score 6):

The error you are seeing is because EXTERN.h is not in the include path.
It looks like it's not on your g++ command line because the perl script is failing

Can you run

```
perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts
```

by itself?  This is the script that gives you the required g++ options.
Are you using [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207/using-the-result-of-a-command-as-an-argument-in-bash) () for quotes around the perl in your command line?  That will cause the perl command to run.

```
g++ fn-test.cpp -o t `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
```

The backticks will run what's inside the backticks then put the output of the command on the command-line.

Comment: yes I could run the perl -MExtutils:: by itself. now when I run g++ fn-test.cpp -o t `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
it seems like it compiled now with the backticks

Comment: any idea why it might have removed Date/Manip.pm by running the force install on ExtUtils::Embed