# Use the result of a command

Tags: bash

How do I use the result of a command from the terminal?

e.g. lets say I use locate to find the path of a file.

```
locate -br ^filename.c$
```

can I write something like:

```
vim (locate -br ^filename.c$)
```

to directly open the file with vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the result of a command as an argument in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207/using-the-result-of-a-command-as-an-argument-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *command substitution*:

```
vim $(locate -br ^filename.c$)
```

Older syntax, less recognizable and thus not encouraged:

```
vim `locate -br ^filename.c$`
```