# Learning linux, can I copy result from whereis (package)?

Tags: linux

I'm taking a linux course and want to know if it's possible to do something like the following:

```
cd (whereis cmatrix)
```

Since linux is slowly transforming my brain to do things quickly and efficiently, I'm sure there's a way to do this so I don't have to type out the entire directory.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the result of a command as an argument in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207/using-the-result-of-a-command-as-an-argument-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), but you probably meant to use `which` instead of `whereis`.

```
path="$(which cmatrix)"
cd "${path%/*}" # "%/*" strips the trailing filepath
```

or

```
cd "$(which cmatrix | sed 's#[^/]*$##')"
```

If you have [`dirname`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dirname.1.html) available, then:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which cmatrix)")"
```

Don't forget to quote the substituted value!

Comment: Thanks, but the following is more what I need since "which cmatrix" isn't a directory: cd "$(which cmatrix | sed 's/cmatrix//')", trying to make it generic now